# Unable to change width and height on image

Tags: javascript, css

I have added two images to my web page which have loaded fine, however when I try to change the height, width, border-radius, etc with CSS it ignores this and stays at the original shape and size. Any help on what is causing this?

My HTML:

```
   <div class="tile-image"></div>
   <div class="tile-image"></div>
```

My CSS:

```
   .tile-image {
    width: 432px;
    height: 192px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

My JavaScript:

```
 data = {
 "tiles" : [
 {
 "img" : "example.jpg"
 },
 {
 "img" : "example.jpg"
 }
 ]
 };

data.tiles.forEach((item) => {
let img = new Image();
img.src = item.img;
tile = document.getElementsByClassName("tile-image")[0];
tile.appendChild(img);
});
```

Comment: Looks like your changing the CSS on the image container, not the actual image. Also, `object-fit` will not work on a `div`. `object-fit` is for how a _replaced_ element is positioned, for instance, a `video` or `img` tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit - Your styles should either target the image, or in the case of your `border-radius` you'll need to also set `overflow: hidden`

Comment: it seems that you're appending all images to the very first `div` element. Check this line: `tile = document.getElementsByClassName("tile-image")[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set your image width to the size of the container.

Add this to your css:

```
.tile-image img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

Or maybe, what you are trying to achive is this:

```
.tile-image img {
   width: 432px;
   height: 192px;
   object-fit: cover;
   border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a height and width on the parent div but not the images themselves. Add the following CSS:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Should work for you